# Cannot format 500GB USB HD: cannot create partition table

Tags: hard-drive, format

When I use disk utility I get the following error:

```
Error creating partition table: helper exited with exit code 1: Error calling fsync(2) on /dev/sdb: Input/output error
```

gparted also cannot create a partition table.

SMART in disk utility runs fine and tells me the hard drive is healthy. I think the HD was used on a windows computer before. Do I need to use a windows computer to fix this?

how to use windows to fix: http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/188931en?language=en_US

Comment: I plugged it into a windows xp computer and was able to create activate it using disk management.

Comment: Can you post a link or more info related to how you fixed it?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible your partition tables have become corrupted this can happen for many reasons but I have a possible solution that may help anyone who comes across a USB device where **disk utilities** or `gparted` throws you errors when trying to format or partition a faulty USB device.

I've pulled my hair out trying to sort out numerous USB devices that I have corrupted with Ubuntu 12.04.

Ok let's get started.

Plug in your faulty USB device and start up **disk utility** you can find it by typing *disk utility* in the Dash home icon very top left left coroner of the Unity Dash board.

Once it's open look on the left hand side and locate your faulty USB device click on it and a page will open, on the right hand side of the screen you should see Device: then what should look like `/dev/sdb` or maybe `/dev/sdb1` depends on what your screen says.

Open up the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> now type: `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb` where you see `/dev/sdb` after `/dev/` this is where you type what you saw on the **disk utility** screen so if it said `/dev/sdb1` on the disk utility screen then the command would be `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb1`

***STOP*** After typing `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb` if the terminal gives you the following `fdisk: unable to open /dev/sdb: No medium found"` Your device is **BRICKED**, the following commands won't help you in Ubuntu! ***STOP***

Now enter the following commands:

type `n` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
type `p` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
type `1` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now it will ask you where to start the sector/cylinder just hit enter then it will ask you where to end, again just hit enter where going to let it use the default fields.

Next:

type `w` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You should now see:

> The partition table has been altered!

If you see this were in business!

Now you should be out of `fdisk` and back at your home terminal. Now type:
`sudo mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdb` or like I said above if in **disk utility** it said something else then the command would end with `/dev/`? Whatever disk utility said the device name was.

Ok now exit the "terminal" by typing exit then hit enter. Go back to **disk utility** and eject the device if it doesn't allow you make sure `gparted` is not running or any other program that might be interacting with the USB device like the "terminal".

Once the USB device is safely ejected plug the device back in and look at the **disk utility** program again and open the device once it registers now go to *format volume* and try to format the volume to *FAT* with whatever volume name you like. If all goes according to plan the device will format to *FAT* and you will now be able to control the USB device normally.

So now you should be able to reformat and control the USB to whatever format you like.

For those that are wondering why at `sudo mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdb` I didn't just make the device fat instead of ext3 for some reason in Ubuntu after I tried fat instead of ext3 I wasn't able to control the device in disk utilities the same way as the method I described maybe a bug I'm not sure but all my USB devices are now free from errors.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

For Gparted to work the USB drive has to be un-mounted first. Which is unlikely because the hard drive would show in your file system.

I would use gparted live on CD to fix the issue. Get a copy here http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

Answer (score 0):

Install GParted

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Then start GParted

```
sudo gparted
```

Find your USB Drive, make sure you are on the correct USB drive and format it.

Comment: As stated in my question, I have already tried gparted. It produces a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear the 1st answer is right if the disk in disk utility is mounted you cannot format it. It will only be possible to unmount it if it is not in use on your system and as this is needed to format it you will be stuck. The solution as already stated is to use a bootable live CD as the first answer stated.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use Gparted & Others, format this Hard Drive Disk in another COMPUTER. using a HDD External Case.